# Find Coefficients from already fourier function

Tags: trigonometry, fourier-analysis

Hello I have this function and I'm asked

1.Find the period for $f(t)$

2.Find the coefficients $a_n$  and  $b_n$

$$f(t)=2(cos(2t+\frac{\pi}{4})-sin(6t-\frac{\pi}{2}))$$

I know that the period for $sin(6t-\frac{\pi}{2})$ is $\frac{\pi}{3}$

I also know that the period for $cos(2t+\frac{\pi}{4})$ is $\pi$

**1.common period is :**

$$\pi , \frac{\pi}{3} => \pi$$

**2.I don't think $f(t)$  I need to find $a_n$ and $b_n$, can't I read them directly from 
$f(t)$? $a_n=2$ and $b_n=-2$  ?**

Could you please tell me if I'm right/wrong for both questions ?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/897987/principal-period-of-sin-frac3x4-cos-frac2x5

Comment: common period should be $\pi$.

Comment: @mike how about the coefficients ? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $(2)$ use the identities

> $$ \cos(A+B) = \cos(A)cos(B) -  \sin(A)\sin(B) $$
>
> $$ \sin(A-B) = \sin(A)cos(B) -  \cos(A)\sin(B). $$

**Added:** Based on what you put in the comment down you can write $f(t)$ as

> $$ f(t) = -  \frac{\sqrt2}{2}\sin(2t)+\frac{\sqrt2}{2}\cos(2t) -\cos(6t) $$

and Fourier series is

> $$ f(t) = a_0 + a_1\cos(t) +a_2\cos(2t)+\dots + b_1\sin(t) +b_2\sin(2t)+\dots\,. $$

Can you see the coefficients now? As I said in my comment just compare with the Fourier series and you will see only three coefficients are not $0$.

Comment: well I wrote

$$cos(2t+\frac{\pi}{4} )= \frac{\sqrt2}{2}(cos(2t) - sin(2t))$$

and 

$$sin(6t - \frac{\pi}{2})=-cos(6t)$$

if I substitute them in orginal function , it doesn't help me

Comment: @Oleg: When you simplify it the way I said you get the Fourier series and you can readily know the coefficients which are the coefficients of the functions $\cos(2t), \sin(2t)$ and $\cos(6t)$. Just compare with Fourier series and you can notice that the rest of the coefficients are $0$.

Comment: Sir, could you please help me out with that ?

Comment: Sorry, I think you forgot the 2 and a - :

$$ f(t) = 2*(-  \frac{\sqrt2}{2}\sin(2t)+\frac{\sqrt2}{2}\cos(2t) +\cos(6t)). $$

and now my $a_2=\sqrt2$ , $b_2=-\sqrt2$ and $a_6=2$.

Comment: @Oleg: Make sure of your calculations!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20532/discussion-between-oleg-and-mhenni-benghorbal).

Comment: I calculated once again , first time I forgot that my period is $\pi$ not $2\pi$ .
So I got these coefficients for $a_1,b_1,b_3$ but not $a_2,b_2,b_6$, what do you think ?

Answer (score 1):

$$f(t)=a_0+ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n \cos(n x)+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n \sin(n x)$$

Now you can compare what you have in the comment with the formula to read off coefficients $a_2,b_2,a_6,b_6$. All the other coefficients seemed to be zero.

Comment: L = half of Period or $\frac{\pi}{2}$
$$f(t)=a_0+ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n \cos(\frac{n\pi{x}}{L})+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n \sin(\frac{n\pi{x}}{L})$$

and the coefficients that I will get will be $a_1,b_1,b_3$

am I right?

If the period were $2{\pi}$ then , I would've gotten $a_2,b_2,b_6$

Comment: Yes.  You are right!