# What is the period of $\sin 2\theta + \sin \frac{\theta}{2}$

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry, periodic-functions

What is the period of $\sin 2\theta  + \sin \frac{\theta}{2}$? The period of the first term is $\pi$ and that of the second is $4\pi$. Does that mean that the period of the whole is $4\pi$?

Comment: In this case $$T=\text{gcf}(\pi,4\pi)=4\pi$$

See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164221/period-of-the-sum-product-of-two-functions

Comment: @AsdrubalBeltran I voluntarily avoided mentioning $\pi$ to avoid having to explain why $\mathbf{Z}[\pi]$ is a UFD, even if we both know it is ;-)

Comment: @RobertGreen I agree.

Comment: @Simon, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/897987/principal-period-of-sin-frac3x4-cos-frac2x5

Answer (score 0):

It is equal to the smallest $>0$ generator of $2\mathbf{Z} \cap \frac{1}{2}\mathbf{Z}$ as $\mathbf{Z}$-module. So what is the smallest $a\in\mathbf{Q}_{+}^{\times}$ such that $2\mathbf{Z} \cap \frac{1}{2}\mathbf{Z} = a \mathbf{Z}$ ?

Comment: How about $2$??

Comment: The Fourier transform of $f(\theta) = \sin(2 \theta) + \sin(\theta/2)$ is $i \sqrt{2 \pi } \delta (1-2 r)+i \sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} \delta (r-2)-i \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}} \delta (r+2)-i \sqrt{2 \pi } \delta (2 r+1)$, which gives you the answer immediately.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Is this a joke or ?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Do you mean $f(\theta) = sin (2\theta)\ldots$?

Comment: @SimonKuang So your guess is $2$ ? Can you prove it then ?

Comment: @RobertGreen:  I was following your solution style.

Comment: Simon asked a relatively simple question, and I think it's a question that is best answered without the use of Fourier transforms or complicated terms like "generator" or "Z-module."  This is a question that a person in high school trigonometry should be answering.  Also, David, I don't think your sarcasm helps the problem here.

Comment: @nukeguy Note that OP asked THE period, and not A period. For A period, I would have answered $4\pi$ with this proof : "check it !". But to show that $4\pi$ is THE period, the only way to do it is, definition of THE period (smallest > 0 generator of the group of "periods"), to do what I have done. A period of $g$ is a $T$ s.t. $g(x+t) = g(x) \forall x$, and such $T'$ form a sub-group of $\mathbf{R}$, etc etc... and THE period of $g$ will be the generator of this subgroup, if it has one...

Comment: From the Fourier transform we can see that the lowest frequency corresponds to $r = 2$, and others are integral portions of that.  Thus the period $T$ is $2 \times 2\pi = 4\pi$.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork This is not a proof, but anyway, that's not the point.

Comment: @SimonKuang BTW you was right for $2$, so that you get that the period you're looking for is... $2 \times (2\pi)$. ;-) Beware of something, saying "the period" and "a period" of a periodic function are very different things, as I'm sure you'll see later in your studies.