# Two periodic functions f and g have periods $2\pi$ and $3\pi$ respectively. Is their sum be periodic?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

> Two periodic functions $f$ and $g$ have minimum positive periods
>   $2\pi$ and $3\pi$ respectivelly.
>
> Is the sum of these functions periodic? Justify.

My books states the solution is

> Yes, because both functions also admit $6\pi$ as period.

Can someone explain this problem to me? Is there any property/identity that I am supposed to use to solve this? I have no clue other than 6 is a multiple of 2 and 3, but I'm not sure if that helps.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/897987/principal-period-of-sin-frac3x4-cos-frac2x5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general principle here is that if something has a period of $T$, it repeats itself every $T$.  That means it also repeats itself every $2T$, as well as every $3T$, and so on.

If you have two functions $f$ and $g$ with different fundamental periods, and you want to know if some combination of $f$ and $g$—some function of them, in other words—is also periodic, what you want to do is see if there is some single value that is a multiple of both of those periods.

In this case, with the periods being $2\pi$ and $3\pi$, there is a common multiple of both of those.  In fact, there are an infinity of them (as there must be), but the lowest (positive) one is $6\pi$.  It does not matter that $6\pi$ itself is irrational; what matters is that it is an integer multiple of the two original periods: It is $3 \times 2\pi$, and it is $2 \times 3\pi$.

We can see this more directly as follows:

- $f$ repeats every $2\pi$, so it also repeats every $4\pi$, and also every $\fbox{$6\pi$}$.
- $g$ repeats every $3\pi$, so it also repeats every $\fbox{$6\pi$}$.

LStU's answer shows how to demonstrate this more rigorously.  The above is just the intuition for finding the right period to try out.

Answer (score 3):

$$f(x+6\pi)=f(x+4\pi)=f(x+2\pi)=f(x)$$
$$g(x+6\pi)=g(x+3\pi)=g(x)$$
so
$$f(x+6\pi)+g(x+6\pi)=f(x)+g(x)$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** You are supposed to use the definitions of *periodic function* and *period*.

Comment: ... and the other solution shows you very clearly how to use the definitions.